# how to override || in c++

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, overriding, overloading

How I can override `||` to cout something? I tried like these, but it doesn't work

in main:

```
obj || 1;
```

in class:

```
ostream& MyClass::operator||(ostream & i)
{
    if (i > 0) 
    { 
        cout << i;
    }
    else 
    {

    } 
    return *this;
}
```

Comment: Care with overload of `operator ||` or `&&`, as there are no longer short-circuit evaluations.

Comment: It is difficult to offer solutions when the problem statement is simply, ["it doesn't work"](http://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/).  Please [edit] your question to give a more complete description of what you expected to happen and how that differs from the actual results.  See [ask] for hints on what makes a good explanation.

Comment: but I just got answer. I had problem with overload this operator, because nothing was shown in cout. I needed to know why not disappear when I try overload operator

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are declaring your class's `operator||` incorrectly.

Your `main` code is not passing in an `ostream` object, it is passing in an integer instead, so the `operator` needs to take in an integer as input, eg:

```
class MyClass
{
//...
public:
    MyClass& operator||(int i);
//...
};
```

```
MyClass& MyClass::operator||(int i)
{
    if (i > 0)
    {
        cout << i;
    }
    else
    {
        //...
    }
    return *this;
}
```

[Live Demo](https://ideone.com/E8a3Em)

Comment: Correct answer. I think the confusion is due to the fact that member `operator ||` is still a binary operation, just with a hidden `*this` parameter as the left-hand operand. It might be helpful to stress that the one explicit parameter is the right-hand operand.